# Clear all cookies - JAVA

Tags: java, jsp, cookies

I'm creating a web application using JSP. In this application I want to use cookies. I have created some cookies in my application and I can get them back. Those are working properly. Now I want to clear all the created cookies in my application. How can I do it? Below is what I tried up to now.

**creating cookies**

```
 <%
Cookie custoName = new Cookie("cname",custName);
Cookie custoMobiNo = new Cookie("cmno",mobiNo);
response.addCookie(custoName);
response.addCookie(custoMobiNo);
%>
```

**getting cookies**

```
<%
Cookie[] cookiesCust = request.getCookies();


cookiesCust[1].getValue();
cookiesCust[2].getValue();
.
.
.
.
%>
```

Anyone can help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clear a cookie, you have to add the cookie to the response again, but this time with an empty value, the max age set to 0, and the cookie path set to `/`. So, to clear all cookies, you would have to:

```
<%
for (Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
    cookie.setValue("");
    cookie.setMaxAge(0);
    cookie.setPath("/");

    response.addCookie(cookie);
}
%>
```